# Reducing objc_msgSend and retain/release calls

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

The performance overhead of calling methods/properties in Objective-C is killing the performance of my iOS app; the Xcode profiler (aka, Instruments) attributes 70% of the latency to `objc_msgSend`, `_retain`, and `_release`.

In my code, so far, I make about 1100 calls to my `XROpenGL` class's instance method `renderSprite(XRSprite)` which is an overloaded method of `renderSprite(XRSprite,int,int,int)` which in turn invokes no less than five other methods, many of which access properties from `XRSprite`. As you can imagine, there's ALOT of messages  being sent around.

Do I have any options apart from rewriting the critical sections of the code in C++?

Comment: Do you mean `objc_msgSend()`?

Comment: **when the method dispatching becomes a problem, you're doing it wrong!** really

I would look with instruments what to optimize. Often the key is to use mutableBuffers or to REUSE objects -> **because what's expensive is allocation**

Comment: I disagree with the closing of this question.  However, I think the question needs some improvement.  First, `renderSprite(XRSprite)` and `renderSprite(XRSprite,int,int,int)` don't describe instance methods in Objective-C; in Objective-C, we don't call methods by putting parentheses at the end of the method name.  You need to post real code.  Second, if you want to talk about your profiler results, post your profiler results - either by copy'n'paste or by posting a screen shot.

Comment: the question is just wrong. he claims that method dispatching is the problem -which in my experience- is only a symptom. + he has no code and no results => very broad + no good fit for QA

Comment: Closed before I could fulfill the request of posting code samples and/or screenshots of the profiler. I'm done with the question though, it seems [game developers don't use objective-c](http://www.vellios.com/2010/08/22/why-game-devs-dont-use-objective-c/). The performance of my app in Objective-C initially was at 7FPS, after extensive optimizing (ditching properties in favor of member variables, removing method overloading, combining methods to reduce messages, etc) I got it up to 27 FPS. I don't think I can get it any faster (and still maintain an OO design) without switching to C++.

Comment: the idea is that a questions can be reopened

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is that 6,600 calls per frame?  I'll assume so for the sake of discussion, at 60 FPS for a total call count of 396,000 just for your explicit method calls.  If you assume the pessimistic case, objc_msgSend's overhead (versus a C function call) is still only O(100) cycles.  So on a modern iDevice you're looking at ~4% of your CPU time, very roughly.  Not a huge deal.  You might get a retain or two and corresponding releases for each call, but retain/release are relatively fast so we'd again be talking single-digit percentages.  "Runtime overhead" of this nature of up to ~10% isn't considered egregious, generally, though it's not optimal.

So, the questions I have for you are:

1. Can you post your code?
2. Can you post more detailed profile information (e.g the exact breakdown between the various top 10 methods, as well as perhaps callstacks for the major ones)?
3. Are you sure the time is actually spent in objc_msgSend et al, and not merely in its children?
4. How many calls are you really making?  As in measured, not assumed.
5. Can you use ivars instead of @properties, to remove some of the method calls?
6. Along those lines, are you caching the properties you do access when using them multiple times in one method?
7. Can you refactor to reduce the number of method calls, and/or use vanilla C functions for some things?

Obviously yes, you can rewrite key code in C++.  But for mid-level drawing code you shouldn't have to; C++ is usually left to low-level constructs like vectors and quaternions and other such primitives.

Comment: this isnt an answer either :) -- just saying it is partly identical to my (old, now deleted) answer